# Is there a way to concatenate rows of a dataframe into a single row

Tags: r

I'm playing around with some data mining algorithims, and wanted to concatente the elements of a dataframe(holds different types of vectors).

I've already tried , subsetting the rows using the "[]" operator , assigning that to multiple vectors and pasting them together using the comma as a delimiter and the result is erroneous.

Actual DataFrame :

```
X   Y
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Desired Result :

```
 X      Y
"1,2,3"   "1,2,3"
"2"     "2"
"3"     "3"
```

```
X <- 1:4
Y <- 2:5
X <- as.data.frame(X)
Y <- as.data.frame(Y)
abc <- paste(X, Y, collapse = ",")
```

Comment: You seem to have a confusion between what you are trying to achieve and the sample you provided.
Are you trying to, for each row, concatenate elements of X and Y, or are you trying, for each vector, to concatenate on the first row every element of this particular vector ?

Could you provide a more elaborate example ?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed this is your data:

```
df<-read.table(text = "X   Y
1   1
                       2   2",header=T)
```

and you are going to collapse the columns and save it in the first row.
the following code merge the columns together

```
apply(df,2,function(x){paste(x,collapse = ",")})
```

and you could save the results at the first row

```
df[1,]=apply(df,2,function(x){paste(x,collapse = ",")})

df
    X   Y
1 1,2 1,2
2   2   2
```

OR if you are going to merge the rows and save them in a column:

```
    X <- 1:4
Y <- 2:5
df <- data.frame (X,Y)
df[,(ncol(df)+1)]=apply(df,1,function(x){paste(x,collapse = ",")})
df
  X Y  V3
1 1 2 1,2
2 2 3 2,3
3 3 4 3,4
4 4 5 4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate rows with a function like this.

```
concatenate<-function(m){
for(i in 2:nrow(m)){
vector<-m[1,]
vector<-paste(vector,m[i,],sep = ",")
}
return(vector)
}

m<-as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1),nrow = 2))

concatenate(m)

[1] "1,1" "1,1"
```

But, you will lose all data types.